# Deploying Eclipse dynamic web app after changing java source

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, eclipse-neon

I have a eclipse dynamic web project with backend written  in java. I have configured Eclipse to deploy and run this project using tomcat.

When I change my java source code, build project and run the server in tomcat, sometimes my changes get applied, but sometimes they do not get applied.

When changing java source code, what are the steps I need to follow when running the project, so that changes will be applied?

I am using eclipse jee neon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you changes to the code, follow following steps to test the changes.

- Go to the servers tab in your IDE and remove the existing web module 
  related to your application.
  [image]
- Now right click on the project and build project. Then right click on
  index.jsp file and select Run as → Run on Server